# CallableStatement - InOut Parameter returns null value

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jdbc, plsql

I recently came across a problem and I can't deal with it. Project was created in Spring Boot 2.3.1 with Java 8 and Oracle 12c. Executing PL/SQL block in Java does not work as expected. Every time the INOUT param returns null.
Example to reproduce the problem:

```java
public String executeSQLBlock() throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall(
                "BEGIN\n" +
                "     IF UPPER(?) = UPPER(?) THEN\n" +
                "        ? := 'Test';\n" +
                "      END IF;\n" +
                "END;");
        statement.setString(1, "Test1");
        statement.setString(2, "Test2");
        statement.setString(3, "Name");
        statement.registerOutParameter(3, VARCHAR);
        statement.execute();
        return statement.getString(3);
    }
```

This method returns null instead of "Name" value. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say for sure why the Oracle and/or the Oracle JDBC driver behaves like this.  My best guess is that there's no way to determine whether the third bind variable is an `OUT` parameter or an `IN OUT` parameter.  For a stored procedure or function the relevant parameter can be declared to be `IN OUT`, but there isn't anything similar for anonymous PL/SQL blocks.

JDBC only supports bind variables by position rather than by name, so within a PL/SQL block bind variables can only ever be read once (which would fit an `IN` parameter) or assigned to once (which would fit an `OUT` parameter).  If it supported bind variables by name, maybe it could handle `IN OUT` parameters, but that is not the situation we are in.

One alternative is to declare a local variable in the PL/SQL block, use an `IN` parameter to set its initial value and an `OUT` parameter to obtain its final value:

```java
        CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall(
                "DECLARE\n" +
                "     l_var   VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR) := ?;\n" +
                "BEGIN\n" +
                "     IF UPPER(?) = UPPER(?) THEN\n" +
                "        l_var := 'Test';\n" +
                "     END IF;\n" +
                "     ? := l_var;\n" +
                "END;");
        statement.setString(1, "Name");
        statement.setString(2, "Test1");
        statement.setString(3, "Test2");
        statement.registerOutParameter(4, Types.VARCHAR);
        statement.execute();
        return statement.getString(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this has to do with the fact that you are using an anonymous block.  Using IN OUT implies a procedure of some kind where you are actually passing a value IN or OUT (or both).  Here is a test using a PL/SQL procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_one_if_odd(x IN OUT INTEGER) IS
BEGIN
  IF MOD(x,
         2) > 0 THEN
    x := x + 1;
  END IF;
END add_one_if_odd;
/
```

Here is the Java program to demonstrate.

```
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;

public class InOutTest {
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//your.db.string", "user", "password");
        CallableStatement statement = connection
                .prepareCall("BEGIN add_one_if_odd(?); END;");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            statement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
            statement.setInt(1, i);
            statement.execute();

            System.out.println(i + " " + statement.getInt(1));
        }

        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

Results in the following output:

```
0 0
1 2
2 2
3 4
4 4
5 6
6 6
7 8
8 8
9 10
```

Updated: As you said you are only permitted anonymous blocks.  If you know that a NULL value for your IN OUT parameter is indicative of it not being set (as in your example) you can use wasNull() to detect and handle this scenario.

```
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;

public class InOutTest {
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//your.db.string", "user", "password");
        CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall("BEGIN\n"
                + "     IF UPPER(?) = UPPER(?) THEN\n"
                + "        ? := 'Test';\n" + "      END IF;\n" + "END;");
        String inOut = "Name";
        statement.setString(1, "Test1");
        statement.setString(2, "Test1");
        statement.setString(3, inOut);
        statement.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);
        statement.execute();

        String out = statement.getString(3);
        out = statement.wasNull() ? inOut : out;
        System.out.println(out);
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

Produces "Name" for a non-match and "Test" for a match.